# Volume of two square pyramids put together

Tags: geometry

So suppose I had two square pyramids.

Both have the same base, $(0,0,0),(m,0,0),(0,m,0),(m,m,0)$.

One has an apex at $(a,a,a)$, while the other has an apex at $(b,b,a)$, where $0<a<b<m$.

What is the volume of this entire thing?

First thought is to try stuff with cross-sections, but that does not get me anywhere.

EDIT: Put in a more specific case.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider the two cases:

1. $a$ and $b$ has the same sign
2. $a$ and $b$ has opposite signs.

Comment: I'm just not sure how to solve this problem, even with this Hint. Maybe I should try the easier case $a=b$? I still can't really visualize it.

Comment: Can you visualise one of the pyramids? Perhaps for simple cases like $0<a<m$? Then ask yourself about what points sre in both pyramids.

Comment: I put in a condition that I forgot to put in originally, and I simplified the problem a bit. I'm still having trouble finding the volume.

Comment: That doesn't look simpler to me.

Comment: I guess not simpler, but a more specific example. Fixed.